# How to add all comma separated values in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a question in XSLT.

I have one variable, suppose :

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="string('1.3,2.1,3.3,5.1,11.4')">
```

I want to add all comma separated values.

This is my current code, where I am trying to sum up all csv values which are stored in $sum variable.

```
<xsl:template name="getCount" >
    <xsl:param name="str" />   <!-- $str is having '0.001,0.003' value -->
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:param name="summation" />
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(string($str),string($delimiter))">
            <xsl:variable name="beforecomma" select="substring-before(string($str),string($delimiter))" />
            <xsl:variable name="aftercomma" select="substring-after(string($str),string($delimiter))" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$aftercomma=''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$summation + $beforecomma" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="getindexvalue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$aftercomma" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="string($delimiter)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="summation" select="$summation + beforecomma" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, you may want to go through this link about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That sample should simply give an error, see http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwe, which results in the error "XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 4 in {string(1.3,2.1,3.3,5.1,11.4)}:
    System function string() cannot be called with 5 arguments".

Comment: Thanks Martin. 
As i am new to XSLT, can you plz tell me when it has 2, 3 or 4 arguments??

Comment: You will need to *tokenize* the string to nodes first. This is where your version of XSLT becomes very important, since XSLT 2.0 has a native tokenize() function. Some XSLT 1.0 processors also support a tokenize() function as an extension. Otherwise you'll need to use a recursive named template.

Comment: [string()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) only takes one argument. You probably meant `<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="'1.3,2.1,3.3,5.1,11.4'">` (note the added quotes).

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Yes Michael..you're right.. I tried using recursive template but it din't work unfortunately..as its not changing the value of variable which is being passed to it..

Comment: "*I tried using recursive template but it din't work*" Why don't you post your attempt, so we can fix it, instead of starting from nothing? And, as I said, knowing which processor you use would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `call-template` is a typo and should be a recursive call to the same template

```
<xsl:call-template name="getCount">
```

then you're actually very very close to a working solution.  The error is in

```
<xsl:with-param name="summation" select="$summation + beforecomma" />
```

where you're missing a `$` in front of `beforecomma`:

```
<xsl:with-param name="summation" select="$summation + $beforecomma" />
```

Without the dollar you're looking for a child element named `beforecomma` rather than taking the value of the variable.

---

A few other comments:

- you have a lot of redundant `string()` calls, you could simply say e.g. `contains($str,$delimiter)` instead of `contains(string($str),string($delimiter))`, as the functions you're using automatically coerce their arguments to string.
- your current code requires at least two comma-separated values, it can't cope with being given just one value (for which the sum would just be the value itself).  Structuring your template to cope with this would actually make it simpler:

```xml
<xsl:template name="getCount" >
    <xsl:param name="str" />   <!-- $str is having '0.001,0.003' value -->
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:param name="summation" select="0" />
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($str,$delimiter)">
            <xsl:variable name="beforecomma" select="substring-before($str,$delimiter)" />
            <xsl:variable name="aftercomma" select="substring-after($str,$delimiter)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="getCount">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$aftercomma" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
                <xsl:with-param name="summation" select="$summation + $beforecomma" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$summation + $str" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @user4550002 the stack overflow way to say thank you for an answer that solved your problem is to _accept_ it by clicking the tick mark on the left. When you've gained a few more reputation points you'll be able to give up-votes too.